# Jasig CAS: Remember Me

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I've a strange problem with with my installation of CAS.
Recently we activated the RememberMe functionality with a 3-Month validity of the ticket on RememberMe.

When the session of my client application expires I got sent back to CAS at

```
https://urlOfmyCas/login?service=urlOfClient
```

Even though the CASTGC cookie is there and valid CAS is showing me again the login page.
If I invoke the URL above without service parameter I get redirected to the "Login-Success" page, so CAS knows that I'm logged in.

I would expect CAS to check the cookie log me in and send me back to my client application unless i send the renew parameter.

Did I mess up something in my CAS installation or is this an expected behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today finally it seems like I found the answer.

CAS is creating a long-term-ticket with validity 3 months (no matter what you specify as expiration timeout in your `ticketExpirationPolicies.xml`). The value specified in the [documentation](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Remember+Me) for `rememberMeExpirationPolicy` is for the `ticketCleaner` only. So even if the cookie is still there the cleaner could potentially already have dismissed the TGT in the ticket registry.

If you call /login without service parameter, the system only checks if there is a TGTid in the cookie without checking the ticket registry, so thats why it shows the success-login page, which confused me a bit.

What put me into trouble is that I assumed that the expiration values used in `org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.RememberMeDelegatingExpirationPolicy` are in SECONDS too (like it is in the default configuration), however this class needs the values as MILLISECONDS.
I should have checked that, but as I tried to set it to 3 months and the ticket has a 3 month validity (so I thought to get what I want), together with the strange behaviour mentioned in the paragraph above... My mistake in the end.

Comment: so，do you fix this bug?

Comment: Yes! Like I wrote in this answer it was my fault. Lets say you want to have 1h timeout for rememberMe. In Seconds it would be 3600, however unlike the default configuration, the rememberme class needs it in milliseconds, so you'd need to put 3600000

Comment: thanks @Hons . you mean change the number of `<constructor-arg index="0" value="31536000" />` in grantingTicketExpirationPolicy in ticketExpirationPolicies.xml? i change it. and if i don't restart the application,it's good. after i restart my application,it goes to the cas login page too when i visit like this http://localhost/ink.

Comment: after i reload my application, when i visit ,it goes to the success-login page,but when i visit my application,it goes to the login page too..

Comment: can we talk in email? my email is weizhankui2008@gmail.com .thanks